# How can I view Xbox UWP app data from the file explorer

Tags: uwp, xbox-one, dev-mode

When my Xbox one is in dev mode the web UI shows LocalAppData, however, I can't view the app data in windows files explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to view files in Windows File Explorer. You can only access these apps' files in Xbox Device Portal.
[image]